# Capturing input using tkinter in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Our inventory system generates 10 digit item numbers based on a pattern.   I have written a program that will do the following:

1. Take a 10 digit item number with an incorrect digit and return a list of possible valid item numbers by changing each of digits.
2. Take a 9 digit item number with a missing digit and return a list of valid 10 digit item numbers by inserting a digit
3. Take a 11 digit item number that has extra digit and return a list of valid 10 digit item numbers by removing a digit
4. Take a 10 digit item number with 2 digits transposed and return a list of valid 10 digit item numbers by switching the digits

I have 5 functions that accomplish this task.  A function for each of the above instances and then a function that determines if an item number is valid or not.  This is all working correctly.

Now I would like to start the program with a GUI that presents the above 4 options along with a quit option.  So a menu of sorts listing 1-5 for the user to choose.  Once the user inputs the option number they want 1 thru 5, I need the user to be prompted to input the item number then have the return list of possible item numbers printed back out in the GUI.

I would like to use tkinter to create my GUI if possible as it is the one I have very limited knowledge of.  I am using Python 3.2.2.  Is this possible?

UPDATE::

After looking at the suggestions I have the following code:

```
class App:
def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    self.l=Label(frame, width = 50, anchor=CENTER, justify=CENTER, text="Please choose from the following options: \n1. Option1\n2. Option2\n3. Option3\n4. Option4\n5. Quit")
    self.l.pack()

    self.e = Entry(frame, width=5)
    self.e.pack()
    self.e.focus_set()

    self.w1=Label(frame, text="Please enter 1-5")
    self.w1.pack()

    self.e1=Entry(frame, width=16)
    self.e1.pack()
    self.e1.focus_set()

    self.w2=Label(frame, text="Enter item number")
    self.w2.pack()

    self.button=Button(frame, text="Return List", state=DISABLED)
    self.button.pack()
root = Tk()

app=App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Now my question is how do I take the information from the 2 entry widgets(self.e and self.e1) and use the button to execute a function.

For example, if user enters option 4 on the self.e entry widget and 1234567890 on the self.e1 widget and then presses the button I need to call the function option4(1234567890).

I need both entry widgets to return numbers but seem to be stuck as to how to accomplish that.   I realize in the button widget I need to replace state= with command= but not sure how to bind the e.get() and e2.get() to the button.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm Check out the Introduction, then look at the Label, Entry, and Button widgets. That should be enough to build this GUI.

Comment: Are you asking us to write the program for you? Is there a specific part of the problem that you are having problems with?

Comment: Bryan, yes that was my first thought but I'll try looking at the suggestions from @petem it might help me to retain this better.  I was working on solution but it involved using a textbox then 2 simpledialog but in the end I had 3 or 4 windows open.  I would really like to keep it all in one window if possible.   Thank you both for your help and input.

Answer (score 0):

That has many different solution, bu you anyway have to create a tkinter variable and connect it to your `self.e` Entry. like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
...then you code with class declaration and so on...
self.var1 = tk.StringVar()
self.e = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = self.var1)
```

By than declaration anything you'll type into your e entry, will get put into your var1 variable. You will be able to acces the value of var1 by `self.var1.get()`

And you couple the function `func(*args)` with button the following way:

```
self.btn = tk.Button(frame, text = 'some text', command = func)
```

Note that it is `func`, not `func(*args)`. So `tk.Button` `command` option should get the handler of your function.

Also, try http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/ whch is a good point to sart uderstanding how to do GUIs with tk, in my opinion